# Python code showing EOF error in Visual Studio Code but works fine in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, eof

[image]

the code is

```
name = input("enter your name : ")
print("your name is :" + name)
```

gives an EOF error in visual-studio code but works fine in Visual-Studio
how do I fix the problem in Visual-Studio code ?

Comment: with `"console": "integratedTerminal"` in launch.json I have no problem. What is your launch.json?

Comment: @Johar Rizvi -How are things going? I updated my answer and you can refer to it.
 Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the indentation for the vscode, it usually if there are trailing spaces.

You can do that by simply clicking F1 and then type `trim trailing whitespace` int the search box and select it. 
OR 
`CTRL + K` `CTRL + X` 
If you still get the same issue try changing indentation to tabs/spaces, follow that same thing as F1 and type `indentation` and then select indentation to tabs/spaces as per your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `"console": "internalConsole",`(in /`.vscode`/`launch.json`) I encountered the same problem.

The reason is that in this mode, the result will be executed in `DEBUG CONSOLE`, and currently this terminal is only used for display output, so the code cannot receive the required input, and an EOF error will be displayed. (End Of File: There is an unexpected error at the end of the file.)

**Solution**:

Use other output methods: `"console": "integratedTerminal",` or
`"console": "externalTerminal",`

Reference: [console in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).